# rxjs observable operator lets you wait n-seconds and merge results into one emit?

Tags: merge, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using ngrx store for state management of a todo list.

My delete action deletes each todo in the store individually. So if I delete 5 in succession, the store will fire 5 new emits.

Is there an rxjs operator which lets me wait like 0.5, collects all emits and merge it into one?

Thanks

Comment: [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) should be close to what you want, but there's no need to merge - the store's latest state is all you should need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bufferTime and skip empty value, that should collect everything every 2sec in an array

```
 var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click').mapTo('clicked')
 var buffered = clicks.bufferTime(2000).filter(value=>value.length>0);
 buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```